# How to avoid capitalization by native2ascii in IntelliJ?

Tags: netbeans, properties, intellij-idea, properties-file

The capitalization of native2acii in properties file is different between the feature of NetBeans and the one of IntelliJ.

NetBeans:

```bash
required.false=\u4e0d\u8981
```

IntelliJ:

```bash
required.false=\u4E0D\u8981
```

How can I configure the capitalization in native2ascii?

Answer (score 1):

Found at least `IntelliJ` configuration for the capitalization.

If you write the following line additionally

```
idea.native2ascii.lowercase=true
```

into

```
[IntelliJ Intalled Path]/bin/idea.properties
```

then you have lowercase ascii characters in properties files.

But how to configure it on `NetBeans` I don't know yet.